# Is there a formal word for dry texter?

Tags: word-request

A dry texter is a person who does not like to continue the conversation. Would it be introvert?

Answer (score 0):

No, because **introvert** is not a formal word, and introverts continue texts all the time. The reason why conversations die is not because one of the two people is an introvert. There are many, many reasons why this happens.

Comment: **Introvert** is not a formal word?

Comment: People do not use it exclusively in formal writing, no. It's used in informal contexts all the time.

Answer (score 0):

There is almost certainly no formal word for something like this.

Introvert is a personality type: typically quiet, reserved, and thoughtful. Introverts don't seek out special attention or social engagements.  It has little to do with whether someone replies to texts.

In formal writing, you would use a phrase such as "A person who does not respond to text messages"

> 12 percent of people reported "often not responding to a text" and 6% claimed that they never responded.

It is fairly common, in formal reports, to define a term for convenience.

> In this paper we classify "dry texters" as people who receive at least one text per day, but respond to less than 15 percent of them... Dry texters are predominantly younger and ...."

There may be correlations with personality types.

> Our research found no correlation between being a dry texter and introversion, as measured by the McCroskey introversion scale. However, there was a correlation (p=0.02) with the Levenson Self-Report Psychopathy Scale.

And so on (all examples here are made up and don't represent real research)